# iOS 7 - Unable to present UIImagePickerController on tabbed application

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on a tabbed application which has 5 `UITabBarItem`. On the second `UITabBarItem` I would display the photo album using an `UIImagePickerController`, but the result is a strange black-white screen (I will post it at bottom).

Here is my `SecondViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIImagePickerController  <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@end
```

and `SecondViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

        UIAlertView *noLibraryAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                    message:@"No photo library!"
                                                                   delegate:nil
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [noLibraryAlertView show];
    } else {
        self.delegate = self;
        self.allowsEditing = NO;
        self.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    }
}
```

But when I select the second `UITabBarItem` the app shows this:
[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked which branch of your `viewDidLoad` (if either) is being executed?

Comment: Post the code that actually creates and displays the image picker.

Comment: @PhillipMills the method is executed completely, I checked it with breakpoints.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't understand your question..

Comment: Post your code where you call `[[SecondViewController alloc] init...]` and `presentViewController...`.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't call those methods..

Comment: Then how do you attempt to display the image picker?

Comment: @rmaddy you have right, I forget to specify that I use storyboard with a root view controller (UITabBarController) called TabBarController which has a relationship with SecondViewController. So when I select the 2° UITabBarItem, TabBarController shows SecondViewController.

Answer (score 1):

According to [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) a UIImagePicker must be presented modally:

> Present the user interface. On iPhone or iPod touch, do this modally (full-screen) by calling the presentViewController:animated:completion: method of the currently active view controller, passing your configured image picker controller as the new view controller.

So it won't work in a tabbarcontroller or as a child of another controller.

Comment: Also, according to the docs, `UIImagePickerController` does not support subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

Officially you can't subclass `UIImagePickerController`. 
However, assuming that you are using storyboard to instantiate `SecondViewController`, I found that changing the code like this would work:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        // other settings
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

        UIAlertView *noLibraryAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                     message:@"No photo library!"
                                                                    delegate:nil
                                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                           otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [noLibraryAlertView show];
    }
}
```

Your code wasn't working correctly because you were setting the `sourceType` after the view was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, it was a stupid problem in

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

It was an autocomplete mistake, but many thanks to all for informations about presentation and subclassing of `UIImagePickerController`.